# How to post messages in Microsoft Team Channel with an image as attached using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I've a requirement, where I've to send some default messages to the Microsoft Team channel with an attached image file using the Microsoft Graph API.

By looking into the [Microsoft Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessageattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0), I've come across following JSON representation.

```
{
  "id": "string (identifier)",
  "contentType": "string",
  "contentUrl": "string",
  "content": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "thumbnailUrl": "string"
}
```

However, I couldn't understand how can I use this JSON representation to post message with a file as an attachment to a team's channel using the Graph API.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
```

Would appreciate any guide/tip/example thank you.

Comment: Hi Ali. I haven't tested this myself, but just an idea - I think the attachement has to be stored somewhere else, e.g. inside SharePoint or on a public web address, so what you're doing with this operation is sending an "embedded" link to the item. Just a suggestion...

Comment: Hi @HiltonGiesenow so you're saying I should first upload the attachment to some common SharePoint location and from there I should get the link and send it as an attachment link in the chat message? Do we have any example available for me to check it out?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Is there any common folder in sharepoint where all the attachment goes to?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean - it's worth testing out. Before trying to automate upload, just try with an existing document. In terms of "common" folder, you could upload to the SharePoint site that exists for your team already - the "File" tab is actually a SharePoint folder behind the scenes (there's an option on the menu to open in SharePoint)

Comment: @AliAsad - You can send attachment to teams using graph API. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-file-attachments)? Try if that helps

Comment: hi @Nikitha-MSFT this looks good. However, as per our use case, we don't want to go into extra step to upload the file on sharepoint and then share its link in the chat. Is there anyway we can send file attachment as a byte of data in the chat message? Our max size for the file would be 1 MB

Comment: If you want to share the image as the attachment using The file must already be in SharePoint. Could you please check the note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-file-attachments)?

Answer (score 3):

To send the image in Microsoft Teams Channel message, use the following request body.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<div><div>\n<div><span><img height=\"297\" src=\"../hostedContents/1/$value\" width=\"297\" style=\"vertical-align:bottom; width:297px; height:297px\"></span>\n\n</div>\n\n\n</div>\n</div>"
    },
    "hostedContents":[
        {
          "@microsoft.graph.temporaryId": "1",
          "contentBytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASkAAAEpCAYAAADPmdSCAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMTZEaa/1AAAhr0lEQVR4Xu3d76tdV50GcP+EvJu3/QuGvJgXxSk0Y8QwzZRmCG2lQkjrkM4UjOmLgmAt0bQGLqipo1ghmIhSRBIMbV+UpmiIRSYV9IqmHaqNgRJbUGqoA30xMGe+z+1ZNyfrPuec/WN9115r7yfw6Y917zlnn+9e68ne66y9z8dms1kjTzzxxC6zxxw3h80d7Pekfti3832MfX3A7GK/J5IDbYxZJz1mbppZ5JJRBx4J7Etzar5vY8fZY0S80cZF6JxRZ41dN7vZY6Uetg8RUJvzfbrMWfZYEU+0MbBOicN+1lljOMo6zJ5Dymf7bvd8H7J9G9vDnkPEC20MrEMuO/Rf5hR7HimX7TOcyrN9ucwF9jwiXmhjYB0Sc06so66ieaoKYB+Zs/N91sYl9nwiXmhjgA4ZddCmNE9VMNs3OI1fN/+0jEJKsqKNATpk1EHb0DxVgWyfYBlJ0/knRiElWdHGAB0y6qBd6BOhQti+aDv/xCikJCvaGKBDRh20K5xaaJ5qIKi96TL/xCikJCvaGKBDRh20D5xiaJ4qM9TcdJ1/YhRSkhVtDNAhow6aguapMrFa45KWPvNPjEJKsqKNATpk1EFT0TyVM6vxuisFulJISVa0MUCHjDpoSjgF0UXKiVlNMf90YV5jDwopyYo2BuiQUQdNDaciuswiEatl6vknRiElWdHGAB0y6qBejrHXl+ashh7zT4xCSrKijQE6ZNRBPeEjci1T6MDq1vYayz4UUpIVbQzQIaMO6k3zVC1YrTD/lHsfKaQkK9oYoENGHTQHzVM1YDXC/BOukWQ19KSQkqxoY4AOGXXQnHQnyCWsNri1b475J0YhJVnRxgAdMuqgueGjdM1TLbB65Jx/YhRSkhVtDNAhow46BMxTTf5yGqvBEPNPjEJKsqKNATpk1EGHglObA2wb27hx40bnSXl7bKcjuq6PW2Tvvc3tfb0ppCQr2higQ0YddGid56ksLM6am6b1Udn8sZumVeDg9+eP63wZkL1nzD+xWgxFISVZ0cYAHTLqoCVoPU+FkDCzuVZBFT22cVDh9+a/Hx7bOqjsfaa6vUpKCinJijYG6JBRBy1F49sTIxwWgiJoFFT2O+yxa4MKP5//XvzYRkFl7w3zT96Xt3SlkJKsaGOADhl10JJgjmblbV8QClFILFoZVPazVY9dGlRon/+cPQ5WBpW9p7639/WmkJKsaGOADhl10BLRr9FCGEThwNCgsrYmj90RVPj/eTv7/UU0qOy9pLi9rzeFlGRFGwN0yKiDlgrbuR0YCIEoFFa5Lajsv9s8djuo8O/5/7PfY7aDCttuSpx/YhRSkhVtDNAhow5asq15Kgz+KAya2Aoq0+WxCKY75v9mP18FwdTn66WGoJCSrGhjgA4ZddCiPf300x9cv379f0kYFOub3/zm/7D3UrDkIXXz4393hzlrLk3IBaNrVBugjQE6ZNRBi7exsTG7du0aDYTSnDlzhr6HwiULKRukIZxmE4bAUlitQBsDdMiog1ahhqCqNKCgd0jZoFQ47aSwWoI2BuiQUQetRslBVXFAQeeQskGocFpPYRWhjQE6ZNRBq1JiUFUeUNA6pGzQKZzaU1jN0cYAHTLqoNUpKahGEFDQOKRskCmc+pt8WNHGAB0y6qBVKiGoRhJQsDakbFApnNKbbFjRxgAdMuqg1RoyqEYUULA0pGwQDRlOGMRdXDfs+UqFbZ5UWNHGAB0y6qBVu3LlCg0Rb2xbKrYjpGzQDBlOeN1eX95hjz9sFFaFoo0BOmTUQaumkEpiO6RskFQdTjF7PoVVgWhjgA4ZddCqKaSSwKAYVTjF7PkVVgWhjQE6ZNRBq6aQ6ufpo/8xe/1f/uG9aHDk4h5OMXs9hVUBaGNgHVMhlQDblpognC4f+DgbEDlkD6eYvb7CakC0MbAOqpBKgG1LDaYeTjHbHoXVAGhjYB1VIZUA25aSKZxWs+1TWGWEgrM3JJJb8eEUs+2tMayqo5CSoVUXTjHbfoWVn0sKKRlK9eEUs/ejsEpn+/RUISW5jS6cYvb+FFbd7Zg7U0hJLqMPp5i9X4VVc0sn9hVS4m1y4RSz96+wWm7tp44KKfEy+XCKWT0UVrc0XhKhkJLU3jR/zzqbfMTqM+WwahxOgUJKPNw0xw39Knr5iNVnSmHVOpwChZR4Ulg1YPUZc1h1DqdAISU5KKwasPqMKax6h1OgkJKcFFYNWH1qDqtk4RQopGQICqsGrD41hVXycAoUUjIkhVUDVp+Sw8otnAKFlJRAYdWA1aeksHIPp0AhJSVRWMkOCikpkcJKtimkpGQKK1FISRUUVhOmkJKaKKwmSCElNVJYTYhCSmqmsJoAhBR2MnXx4N3XX3zwUzPm9L/unT2w5x+r8vA9n5r9273/nB3blpI9s/+f6D6HAb/qahWEFdbtTAHu0zWpUKaNwRMrvnfvyJEjszvvvFNG6IEHHqD7HP7zyCEWEuIPizgPs3E6drQxsE6pkJoghVRRJhtOAW0MrFMqpCZIIVWEyYdTQBsD65QKqQlSSA1K4RShjYF1SoXUBCmkBqFwWoI2BtYpFVITpJDKSuG0Bm0MrFMqpCZoVUid+vfDH0aDTLpRODVEGwPrlEtDKvjc5z43e+ihh2Z33XUX7fC1uvfee2c//OEPZ7/+9a9nN27c2PLWW29ttX3605+mj6kV9h2C6bHHHqP7OIK1OmO6F3duCqeWaGOADhl10KUef/zx2f79++kgqM0XvvCF7WBa5rvf/S59bG327t279RcN26dLXAr9A4NtPujYYJTbKZw6oo0BOmTUQdeqPaiaBFSAoyr2HLVAQOEvF7YfV9gOqQCDbz4I2eCcOoVTT7QxQIeMOuha6PS1nvrhFI+F0SpHjx6lz1WDlkdQwY6QCjAY54OSDdapUTglQhsDdMiogzaCOSo2KEqHIyMWRKu89tpr9LlKd99999F918DSkAowOOeDlA3esVM4JUYbA3TIqIM2gr+h2cAoHQuhJnAExp6vZI888gjddw2sDakAg3U+aNlgHhuFkxPaGKBDRh20MTYwSoZP7FgANfHZz36WPmfJOsxFBY1DKsDgnQ9iNrhrp3ByRhsDdMiogzbGBkbJPvOZz9AAagKPZc9ZMrbPGmodUoEN5j1jw96npEUbA3TIqIM2dvfdd9PBUSocDbEAauLEiRP0OUvG9llDnUNKpAvaGKBDRh20sX379tHBUao+IfX1r3+dPmfJ2D5rSCElWdHGAB0y6qCN1bZeCkHDAqiJ2hZ24i8Qts8aUkhJVrQxQIeMOmhjuMyCDZBSdVl+ELzyyiv0OUuFv0DYPmtIISVZ0cYAHTLqoI3hI242QEqF9U4sgJpiz1kqrGNj+6whhZRkRRsDdMiogzaGj7jZACnRJz7xCRo8bdR00XHDC4mXUUhJVrQxQIeMOmgrtcxLtbleb5la5qXwqSvbVy1smj1z+iopcUcbA+uEvULq0KFDdKCUBnNKLHjawC1d2HOXZtW9onpCX4FT5rhBiO1m/UqkDdoYzDsd65CNlb5eqs9K8xiOyNhrlKTHSvM+cPR1wYTw0hGYNEYbA+tMvUOq9KOpn/zkJzRwuij9aKrHRcUerhsE1zGjIy5ZijYG1nl6hxSUejTVZwHnMqUeTeH2OQMdRTV10yi0ZAfaGFhnSRJSpd4Pve+yAwa3GManhez1htRz2cEQcKSF+a0DrG/KdNDGwDpIkpCCgwcP0sEzFHwax0ImBZxCstccSs/FmyXAUdZZo8CaINoYWKdIFlKA29WyQZRbiiUH65Ry0XHHWwSXLASW7kAwEbQxsI6QNKQwWLyDCpPDTz311Oz8+fOzzc3N2QcffLDt/Rdenr2378Gs/nLy2du2Adv08ssvzzY2Nra2lb2HVDAP1XPhZulwSohPDO9g/VfGgTYGtvOThhR4BRWCKQ4lJmdQxQHF/P73v98KrE9+8pP0fXU1gYCKYdJdR1cjRBsD2+nJQwoQVKlWoyOcMNBZACyTI6iaBNSid999d/btb387SViN8BSvDRxdHTZaizUStDGwHe0SUkGfL2zA3TCbHDkt4xlUbQNqEQL30Ucfpe+5CXxAwWo9QZi7wqmgwqpytDGwHewaUoAvbWh7gzycHrEB3pZHUPUJqEXf//736XtfBjXEUg9W44lTWFWONga2Y91DKsAAa3IKiAlxNqi7ShlUqQIqwDqudad/CCes6mc1ldsorCpFGwPbodlCKsCRFU4D2dFV6oAKUgRV6oAKcEobBxXmnHBa1/HLPadOYVUZ2hjYjsweUjEcYeEGevjYng3iVPoElVdABVevXt06WtLpXFIIK30VVQVoY2A7cfCQgnPnztHBm1qXoPIOqODnP/85rY30tnV/LNb/pQy0MbCdN3hIfe1rX6OD1kuboMoVUMHp06dpjSQJrLPSKWCBaGNgO23wkGq7BiqFJkGVO6Dgz3/+8+xLX/oSrZMkgVPAY2wsyHBoY2A7bNCQwje4sMGaw6qgGiKggpdeeonWSpJCv9ftYgpBG4P5zmI7MYt33nmHDtRcWFANGVCBjqayOc7GheRFGwPbSYOF1JBHUYsWg6qEgAIdTWWFiXVdwDwg2hjMdxDbce5++9vf0gE6BARVKQEFOMJkNRM3Wq4wINoItlNwzx62w9w988wzdHDKLfjUk9VOXOkTwAHQRtsRgwUUlHKqVzKd8g0Gd1nQpHpGOxpsBwwaUICFi2xgyi04HWa1k2x0+pfJbf9jhR88oKCk+aiSsdpJVmcXx4/42P4PFDzaAYNhA1J20lKEIuDDJc1TOdr6hxW5mIACNiBlp29961u0fpKd5qkcFRdQwAak7KSQKgqWKehCZQcIqcHWQi3DBqTspJAqkibUE0NI7TJFBRUbkLKTQqpYCqqEtv5hRS0qqNiAlJ2w6JXVT4qgT/4S2f4PKyqCqoj5qaEvLK4Fq50URUGVwI4GK+ypqNDZaZ3UerjPFqudFEdB1RNttMLiyxVZwbPAJR9sYMotup1wVRRUPdBGsMLuNvhYlRXdVe5bBtcI1zey2kmxFFQd0cbACnuHGWRCXfNSq2m1eZUUVB3QxpgVN/s81auvvkoHp3ww++Uvf0lrJlXQ3T5boo2MFfeAyXb6p3tKLaf1UdXTOqoWaOMyVlyc/mW7pbBu2bKTbtEyGgqqhmjjOlbgY1HBXeBoCl/jxAbrVOkoajRwVqKLkhugjU2gwMb9qErLEW7BPB2rkVQLQaUveViDNrZhRcZRletclRZ3fvTlC/pEb5R0P6o1aGNbVmTMVeEm9Wwn9IbBOeXTPrx3ffHCqF1g40o+Qhu7smLvMbgBGNsRvWCQTjWoTp8+TWsio6KlCUvQxr6s4LisJvkp4NSCCu9VK8snRTfNI2hjClZw3FXhuEkaVggqXFzLBrUXBAWOZnIGpE7xJkkT6QRtTMmKnjysMEeVYw0VJqsXgwJLInIEJD4o0CT5ZF1i42jKaKMHK37ysMKaIa9r/LD0YVlQnDt3zuWoSqd3Mqf5qQW00ZPtAITVyws7pDcM7BRhhZDAWqQmd7xEgCHIUoQVth3Bp6MnWaD5qTna6M12AI6o2I7pBadmCJk2gYWQwQW7CLquIYH5Kpx+tgksbCMeo0/uZAl8Sq71U4Y2erPiu4TUIgQOTgdxhIIjnhjCwWNiGkdheG72moBtanKkJmJOsfEzNbTRmxXfPaRERmLyp3200ZsVXiEl0szkT/toozcrukJKpLlJn/bRRm9W9CQh9ZWvfGX25JNP0p+JjMxkT/toozcreO+QOnPmzOzGjRtbNjc3tyal0baxsUF/X6Rym2wsTQFt9GYF7xVSiwG1zJUrV7aC6/nnn589++yzsxMnTtDnygFHe9gGbAu2Cdv25ptvKlClrWNsPI0dbfRmxe4cUk0CahUcdSEkLl68ODt//vyW5557bitEgqankIuPgfB8IYjwWmwbgmvXrimopA1crTG5SXTa6M0K3TmkMKgxuNmgrw1CTHNq0tLkvhaLNnqzQvc63RtDUCmgpIdJ3SmBNnqzIveeOK85qBRQ0tOk7pRAG71ZkXuHFNQYVAooSWQySxJoozcrcJKQgpqCSgElCU3maIo2erMCJwspqCGoFFDiYBJHU7TRmxU3aUhByUGlgBInkziaoo3erLjJQwouX75MQ2JoWMTJtlckgdEfTdFGb1bY5CGFxZksIEqBRahsu0V6Gv3RFG30ZoVNGlKlB1SgoBInu9k4Gwva6M2KmiykagmoQEElDka9Cp02erOiJgmp2gIqUFCJg9GuQqeN3qygvUOq1oAKFFSS2Gi/Bos2ekNBowK3UntABQoqSegmG2tjQBu9WUE7hxRuhcIGfK1wixf2PkU6OMzGW+1oozcrZueQwqJILI5kA742OCJk71Gko1EuR6CN3qyYvU73xhBUCihxMroJdNrozQrZe+K85qBSQImj0X2zDG30ZoXsHVJQY1ApoMTZdTbmakYbvVkhk4QU1BRUCijJZFTX89FGb1bEZCEFNQSVAkoyGtUKdNrozYqYNKSg5KBSQElmo1ozRRu9WRGThxRgzRELiaGxbRVxdoCNvRrRRm9WQIWUiK/RfMpHG71ZARVSIr5G8ykfbfRmBVRIifgbxX2maKM3K55CSsTfMTb+akMbvVnxFFIi/kZxLR9t9GbFU0iJ5LGLjcGa0EZvVjiFlEge1S9FoI3erHAKKZE8ql+KQBu9WeEUUiJ5VD8vRRu9WeEUUiKZxOOvNrTRmxVOISWST9V3RaCN3qxoCimRfKpeL0UbvVnRFFIi+Vxg47AWtNGbFU0hJZLPJhuHtaCN3qxoCimRjOIxWBPa6M2KppASyavayXPa6M0KppASyavaLw6ljd6sYAopkbyOs7FYA9roDQWLCpiEQkpkqWpXntNGb1YwhZRIXtV+wkcbvVnBFFIimcXjsBa00ZsVTCElkl+V95aijd6sWAopkfyqXIZAG71ZsRRSIvkppJqyYimkRPKrchkCbfSGYkXFS0IhJbKSQqopFCsqXhIKKZGVzrHxWDra6M2KpZASye+/2XgsHW30ZsVSSInkV+VXr9NGb1YshZRIfu+x8Vg62ujNiqWQEsnvr2w8lo42erNiKaREBhCPxRrQRm9WLIWUyADisVgD2ujNiqWQEhlAPBZrQBu9WbEUUiIDiMdiDWijNyuWQkpkAPFYrAFt9GSF2m1uLhYuFYVUGo899hhtl1Go7l7ntNGLFcgtoEAhlYZCavSqCira6MEK4xpQoJBKQyE1CdUEFW1MzQriHlCgkEpDITUZVQQVbUzJCpEloEAhlcajjz5K22WUig8q2piKFSBbQIFCKo1Dhw7RdhmtooOKNqZgbzxrQIFCKg2F1CQVG1S0MQV709ejIrhTSKVx//3303YZvSLvgU4bU7A3rCOpObatJTt48CBtl1E7y8ZxCWhjKvbGNSdl2LaW7J577qHtMlrFBhTQxpSsAPp0j2xryfbt2zd7/PHH6c9kdIoOKKCNqVkhsgSVQioNhNSRI0foz2RUig8ooI0erCDuQaWQSgMh9eCDD9KfyWhUEVBAG71YYVyDSiGVBkJq//799GcyCtUEFNBGT1Ygt6BSSKWBkLrrrrvoz6R6VQUU0EZPViSFVOEQUnfeeaeu4RsnhdQqViCd7lUghNRDDz1Efy7V0+keY4XRxHklQkjh3+znMgqaOF9kBXEPKFBIpRFCCrReatSqCCramJIVIktAgUIqjcWQ0sXGo1d8UNHGVKwA2QIKFFJpLIaUTvkmoeigoo0p2BvPGlCgkEpjMaTg6NGj9PdkVIoNKtqYgr3pS1ER3Cmk0ohDSqvPJ2Nyt2rZZTYXCuBOIZVGHFJa2DkJ07vpHdgbzxpUCqk04pACTaCP2jRvHxxYAbIF1cbGBg2JobFtLRkLqT179tDflepN+4sYAitEtqBiITE0tp0lYyEFOpoaneIDCmijBytIlqBiITE0tp0lWxZSOpoalSoCCmijFyuMe1BduXKFBsWQ2HaWbFlIgY6mRqGagALa6MkK5BpUFy9epEExJLadJVsVUjia0qUyVSsioGxc7DZ7zGFzbP7fdAnEjoYcrFDHo8Ilc+bMGRoUQ2LbWbJVIQVaN1WveCzmZGPhgLlgboaxscSmQXDtwuPok3mzYrmFVImf8LHtLNm6kMK6Ka1Cr1M8FnOwMYBwur44JhpCmB2nT+rNiuUWUvDmm2+yNzwYto0lWxdSgN9hj5WyxWPRk/X9XQZHTnRcNEWf3JsVyzWkSpuXYttYsiYhBbopXn3isejF+j0CCqdtdEy0QV/AmxXLNaSee+45+maHwraxZE1DSqd99YnHogfr88kCCuiLeLNiuYYUlHTKx7avZE1DCvbu3UufQ8oUj0UP1ucvxWOgD/oi3qxY7iF1/vx5+oaHwLavZG1CCg4ePEifR8oTj8XUrL8fj/t/X/SFvFmx3EPqxIkT9A0PgW1fydqGFGiRZx3isZiS9XWc5q1bXtAafTFvViz3kIJSJtDZtpWsS0iBvgKrfPFYTMn6evKjKKAv5s2KlSWkSjmaYttWsq4hhYl0BVXZ4rGYkvX1Lmuh1qIv5s2KlSWkoISjKbZdJesaUoCJdF02U654LKZi/RyXudD+3xd9QW9WrGwh9eSTT86uXbtG33wubLtK1iekQEFVrngspmL93OVUD+gLerNiZQspeP755+mbz4VtU8n6hhQoqMoUj8VUrJ+fjft9KvQFvVmxsoYUDHkLF7Y9JUsRUqCgKk88FlOxfp50bdQi+oLerFjZQ2rI0z62PSVLFVKgyfSyxGMxFevnCqkUhvqiBrYtJUsZUoCgOnLkCH0tySsei6lYP1dIpTLE/abYdpQsdUgFuiB5ePFYTMX6efJFnAF9QW9WrMFCCnIvS2DbUDKvkIL77rtP81QDisdiCtbHsdKc9v0U6It6s2INGlKQM6jY65fMM6QAtyDWPNUw4rGYgvVx3NSO9v0U6It6s2INHlKQK6jYa5fMO6QC3YY4v3gspmB93G35AdAX9WbFKiKkIMccFXvdkuUKKcAyBU2q5xOPxb6sf7ue6gF9YW9WrGJCCnCTPM/lCew1S5YzpALNVeURj8W+rH+7rTQP6At7s2IVFVKAi5E3Nzdpkfpir1eyIUIKsFQBp4AKKz/xWOzD+rbb9XqL6It7s2IVF1IBbpaX+qiKvU7JhgqpQGHlajcbk21Zv056i+BV6AZ4s0IVG1KAo6rLly/TgnXBXqNkQ4dUgLDCXT91H/WkjrMx2Zb1a9fJ8kV0A7yhUFHhioQV6imu+WPPXbJSQmrR/v37Z4888gjdXmnlutn60s0urD/jCCpbQAHdEG9WpCpCKkBY9VmuwJ6zZCWGVICjK0yyK7B6OcvG5TrWlzEHleUUbxHdGG9WpKpCKsBFyrjtS9ujK/ZcJSs5pBYhsHCEhfura3Foa42Dyvowjp7cP8Vbhm6UNytQlSG1CIGFpQsvvfTS2tBijy9ZLSEVQ2hh2zHpjiMtBddaOPU7zMao9VsEE1aSZz21Y3ZsXEr2AncYvFGk8CmDK6UvXb169ToGNuA0Cp+oYVHlxsYGK2QVEFqnT5/eej8/+9nPtr73LwjvFZPxeK84GsMpJHueEniGFJ7785///Ox73/vell/84hcUaoSff/WrX92aOMeCz64UVo389eTJk//1ne98Z/OnP/3p22+99dZ7NlZpaORGw6Ure0Kk72GD73/vfFU0BjQ6KT5lI8UsRjiS6vNFpFibhecoKaBTh9QXv/jF2Y9+9KPZr371K1qDJkqs09jhL14cPLzxxhtudzhogoZNW/ZEe4zLYSECC4ViRRwCghODxWOFOsIO4YzOwV47lxQhdf/9928dCfUJ8GXwnDgiHbpOU4Ijfzu6+pDtD280dJqyJ0A4ud3sahE65pBhhXDKdUEyAnDIQdgnpBBOL774In1fqQ1dp6lBnXONgUU0fNaxB2KuCad09Ek94bA/53wOdgwGAtsWbxiEQwRz15DCkZPHEeY6eE0cgbL3IumhT7L94IWG0Cr2oGNm0HNUwCmX99+gmP/wOF1pC6e8Oefn2obUww8/3Gu+KRX8BVb6POZY4C8Ftg880CBi7JezrzRdx7NT5twJTeBoARP1bFtTaxNSJ0+epNs7lKGOPqco5aVjq9BAitkvIqCyrzRtAp0y9Sc+Q5x3N5VjADYNqVxzT13gFJ29N0kHZzI5Tu9pKC2yX8JSeJfveE8pxeBF0XP97dAHQpRtfypNQqrkgAq86yR55qdoMAX2C5ggH3z+qam+p0OY+2HPWyLPAbgupGoIqEBB5c/7aIqGE9gPiz3FW6bPqV/Jp3jLeJ36rQqpmgIq0KmfL3yIxeqeyCkaUGA/zLL+KTUEVdtP/YZaYpCCx3KMZSFV2iR5G7k+dJgi9EFW8wRwkLRrWUANdsVzCjhtY8VkHAucRZdQXoeFFJYZsNevBeqk5Ql+WM17wjTT1l1EWUBluW+xtyaL+zC4S1gH1VebUG6ChVQJ66D6Sl0nucVhHG3fnYGFVFXzUMs0+ZvT+Vw6q5SnM3FIYSU5e80aaWW6j8QfOp1azKQ4oHAHA/agKq36ZAcBxh5TK/xNlvK0LwQUrsVD4LPXrJHH6bEkDakdN+NbDCh8mlfNcoOmlk0s1/hp3jqpPsX68pe/vB1SNX6at44+7UsvUUjRu4Vu/4f9wqiOogIszowLOrajqABHCfF77eIHP/jB9lEUe53a6WgqPVbnlpbeznj7P+yXil9V3lU8NzXGo6ig79qpb3zjG9shdfbsWfoaY6C5qXSwNpHVuIWV91vf+of9Eu4LxR48CouH9/gbdExzLDFcdL3Ygdp64YUXtkNqzHXCHB57/9Jez4vxb5skZ7b+Yb9Y1N0NUlvskDmuNRpan/VAf/rTn7ZCCrf8Zc89JroVcRr4i5HVdw3Mf9MvgYht/WP+APZEoxE6ZA0XEPfV9VQGyxjwByE1xgnzmCbQ++u4GBrLnBp/3TsCahSLN9cJA3fMpzAB+7Cgibffftv6xEchNYZFruv0PTWWTp/q4VujWn2DMkIKd9pkTzYqGLgJJviq0OVTPsxFhT8XLlygzztGrBbSTMu5KBw97bHuRYNoldHPRwU4MpjCfFTQZr4Fn+gt/nn11Vfpc46RxwXaU4D+1fCsBFNJx6xb0QBqAiFV5d0Ouqj5bgdtNb1MBgH14YcfWl+49ec3v/kNfc4x0lKE9hoGFMIJNypodWrHIKTYC4xSx08hqtRkUhhBFgcU/rzxxhv0OcdIk+ft4Mjzj3/84/+xWs5hvSUWhvcOp0AhNVKrBt9TTz01e+WVV2z/8z/vvPMOfc4x0p07m8H6whVnIjhqwrRR40/s2lBIjRTu8BB3NIQTJsjff/992/fL/0wppHT7ltUQTpjL/cMf/vC3qHaYCMcndZ0mw9uYVEhdvXqVto8RAhmnc4Cjpt/97ne2v5v9UUhNExYB43QOfvzjH7//+uuvv2undn+x/vCa1QqBhJUA7qF0u9nH/h+sBaOnOz4IxQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
            "contentType": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

For detail, please follow the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).